# Mayavi mlab in Julia v1.1.1 using PyCall

Tags: julia, mayavi

I’m having trouble using `mayavi.mlab` in Julia v1.1.1 even though I have been able to install Mayavi using Conda.

I can do the following using `PyCall`

`mv = pyimport("mayavi") #works`

but cannot do either of the following

`mlab = pyimport("mayavi.mlab")`
or use
`mv.mlab.volume_slice`

I get the following error
`The Python package mayavi.mlab could not be found by pyimport.`

I have tried using `pygui_start` with various backends before importing mayavi to no avail. Is anyone else using Mayavi for plotting in Julia v 1.1.1?